# Bad Source File: can't import subdirectory JAVA

Tags: java

For some reason, I can't import a class from a subdirectory.
I did check the premission but they are 550 and I do not think it is a permission issue. Am I doing something wrong?

MainClass:

```
import etc.*;
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LCM lcm = new LCM(12, 24);
        System.out.println(lcm.findLCM());
    }
}
```

etc/LCM:

```
public class LCM {
    private int number1 = 0 ;
    private int number2 = 0;
    private int lcm = 0;

    public LCM(int num1, int num2){
        number1 = num1;
        number2 = num2;
    }

    public int findLCM(){
        lcm = (number1 > number2) ? number1: number2;

        while (true) {
            if(lcm % number1 == 0 && lcm % number2 == 0){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("LCM: " + lcm + " N1: "+ number1 + " N2: "+number2);
            ++lcm;
        }

        return lcm;
    }
}
```

Directory: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc9WM.png)

> - MainClass.java
> - etc/LCM.java

Error:

```
MainClass.java:4: error: cannot access LCM
        LCM lcm = new LCM(12, 24);
        ^
  bad source file: "./etc/LCM.java"
    file does not contain class etc.LCM
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error
```

Comment: You're confusing packages and directories. A class belongs in a package foo if it has the statement `package foo;`. Not if it's in a directory. The the directory tree must match the package tree. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Comment: You're missing a `package etc;` in the first line of the `LCM.java` file.

Comment: @JBNizet I am using VSC, does that matter?

Comment: @Andreas same question, I am using VSC and compiling it through terminal. Does that have any effect on it?

Comment: @user9358154 No, it does not. It's standard Java for disk-based source files, regardless of IDE used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think the problem is with the package import. Problem looks to be with the way the source files have been configured. I am not sure which IDE you are using. But i suspect that in the build path of your project the "etc" folder is not added to source.

You can solve this by adding etc folder in source. Please find example in the attached image.[image: Here]

Comment: Thank you for your submission. But I was using VS code and just compiling it through the terminal in VS code. So that is a bad idea?